# Ubuntu freezes on login after prime-select intel

Tags: intel-graphics, asus, nvidia-prime

I have an Asus GL553 with Intel 560 and Nvidia GTX 1050 and I'm tried to configure my hybrid cards with nvidia-prime.
I installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 then installed nvidia-381 and ran prime-select intel I had to hard reboot and when I tried to login the system freezes.
I have researched and read all these topics but I can't find a solution.

- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/991853/complete-freeze-with-nvidia-prime/?offset=8
- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/991853/complete-freeze-with-nvidia-prime/?offset=18
- [edited to: shutdown hangs on intel grapics on 16.04 with 4.7.2 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831928/edited-to-shutdown-hangs-on-intel-grapics-on-16-04-with-4-7-2-kernel)
- [NVIDIA-PRIME: Cant switch to intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879856/nvidia-prime-cant-switch-to-intel)
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1637733
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1663926

Has anyone could configure nvidia properly?

Comment: have same issue with https://askubuntu.com/questions/918435/16-04-2-nvidia-970m-intel530-can-not-switch-to-intel-graphics, tried also kernel 4.10, same result :*(
still not solved

Comment: @MikeBelyakov I found this solution. However I couldn't start grub after put the aml file into configuration. https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-305408609 https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1001621/linux/prime-select-nvidia-gt-log-off-doesn-t-work-but-reboot-does-on-375-quadro-m1000m-dell-precision-550/2

Comment: How did you add the file into grub? you need put all in one line like this: initrd ${rel_dirname}/acpi_gpufix ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it.

1.- Make a folder to store the SSDT files. Then extract it from the ACPI tables (run this part as root):

```
# mkdir dsdt
# cd dsdt
# SSDT_FILES=`ls /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/ | grep SSDT`
# for file in $SSDT_FILES ; do cat "/sys/firmware/acpi/tables/$file" > "$file.dat"; done
# cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT > DSDT.dat
```

2.- Make sure you have IASL installed. On ubuntu, sudo `apt install iasl` should suffice. I downloaded the source and compiled it myself to get the latest version, but I don't think thats necessary.

3.- There's a duplicate definition in one SSDT file which won't let us dissassemble it. Find out which one it is and delete it:

```
# grep PRT0 *.dat
Binary file DSDT.dat matches
Binary file SSDT1.dat matches
# mv SSDT1.dat SSDT1.bak
```

So in my case it is SSDT1. Replace it with whatever you get. Do not touch DSDT.dat

4.- Next, we find the SSDT file with the code we need to change. We look for the file with both "NVID" and "OSYS" are present: (There's probably a better way to do this in grep)

```
# grep NVID *.dat
Binary file SSDT10.dat matches
Binary file SSDT3.dat matches
# grep OSYS SSDT10.dat
# grep OSYS SSDT3.dat
Binary file SSDT3.dat matches
```

So in my case it was SSDT3, if its different you replace all further instances of SSDT3 with whatever you get.

5.- Disassemble!

```
# iasl -e *.dat -d SSDT3.dat
```

6.- Hopefully you don't see any errors at this point. Replace all instances of OSYS except the declaration with the constant for Windows 7, and bump the definition block number by one:

```
# sed -i '/^ *External/! s/OSYS/0x07D9/g' SSDT3.dsl
# sed -i '/^ *DefinitionBlock/ s/0x00001000/0x00001001/g' SSDT3.dsl
```

If you have a different BIOS, the Definition Block number might not be 1000. Just open SSDT3.dsl in a text editor and look for DefinitionBlock. Whatever number you see on that line, increment it by one.

7.- Compile everything and hope there are no errors.

```
# iasl -ve -tc -p SSDT3 SSDT3.dsl
```

8.- Make an image:

```
# mkdir -p kernel/firmware/acpi
# cp SSDT3.aml kernel/firmware/acpi/ssdt3.aml
# find kernel | cpio -H newc --create > acpi_gpufix
```

8.- All the following instructions corresponding to Ubuntu and GRUB2. Copy it to the boot folder. the initrd.img it's your default img from boot folder:

```
# cp acpi_gpufix /boot/
```

you can permanently add it to your GRUB by editing /etc/grub.d/10_linux. I had to change the line `initrd ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}` to `initrd ${rel_dirname}/acpi_gpufix ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}`. Then run update-grub2.

**UPDATE**:
Now GRUB support extra initrd: GRUB_EARLY_INITRD_LINUX_CUSTOM=acpi_gpufix.img to your /etc/default/grub

9.- To check if it works:

```
$ dmesg | grep ACPI | grep override
[    0.000000] ACPI: Table Upgrade: override [SSDT-PegSsd- PegSsdt]
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007A715080 Physical table override, new table: 0x0000000079493000
```

Now you can change the GPU wihtout freezes

source:

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-306543064
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1012369/linux/laptop-freezes-changing-video-cards

Comment: I have the same laptop facing the same issues, and was following the steps. Everything was exactly the same, until
7.- Compile everything and hope there are no errors.
where I get
SSDT3.dsl    109:         External (\SGMD, 0x00, 0x00)
Error    6126 -                              ^ syntax error, unexpected PARSEOP_INTEGER
(and a lot of similar errors). Where can I find further info to debug? Thanks!

Comment: Please show me the output of this command: "sudo apt install inxi -y && inxi -F && dmesg | grep -i error" (without quotes) and copy it in pastebin or another online file

Comment: here are the details! https://pastebin.com/750cNjST
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure did you follow the steps very carefully? 
Show me the errors in step 7 and upload it in pastebin please. Thanks.

Comment: All the steps (including 7 with the errors): https://pastebin.com/v8gBGLY3
The only difference is my system is in Spanish, but everything else (the files that match in GREP) is exactly the same.

Comment: If it helps, here's the diff in SSDT3.dsl, before and after the `sed` replacements: https://www.diffchecker.com/2t3aJREP

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the compiler. I'll see what version I have installed to see if that the problem.

Comment: I just updated the tool from https://www.acpica.org/downloads and now the errors are different: https://pastebin.com/DHARTSrH

Comment: avoid it and continue with the steps

Comment: If this is a fix, could you explain what the culprit is in your answer ?

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156341 first response

Answer (score -1):

A long ago i used to have an nvidia laptop,  and have similar issues with gnome. The only that worked for me was to uninstall gnome and used KDE  instead.  But i repeat that was long ago 10~ version i guess.

You can start on command mode to do that:

To boot into `single user` mode you edit the boot instructions for the GRUB menu entry you wish to boot and add the kernel parameter/option `single`. Brief instructions for how to do this are below.

- Hold down the left `Shift` key while rebooting to bring up GRUB menu
- Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry you wish to use.
- Press `e` to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu
  entry.
- Look near the bottom of the list of commands for lines similar to

  linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b\
  6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash
  initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
- Change the middle line in (4) by adding the kernel boot parameter
  single to the end of the line (i.e. after `ro  quiet splash`).

For this example you would change:

```
6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash
```

to

```
6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash single
```

- Press either `Ctrl+X` or `F10` to boot using these kernel options.

**Note:** These changes are **not** persistent. Any change to the kernel boot options made this way will only affect the next boot and only if you start that boot by pressing either Ctrl+X or F10 while still in GRUB edit mode.

Comment: But this doesn't solved my issue. Actually I can login setting up prime-select nvidia. The issue is that I can't turn off my discrete card.