# Selecting intel graphics makes my system crash at boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

i have UBUNTU 16.04 (had 18.04 with the same problem), and the problem is, when I select intel graphics by `sudo prime-select intel`, my system fails to boot. It starts booting, Ubuntu loading animation appears, then it throws me back to a boot console, where underscore is blinking and then it **stops** blinking, which as I think is a system crash.

I can't use my tty (any of them), i downloaded the drivers for intel graphics, but it makes no difference. And also i've installed nvidia drivers (396) and bumblebee.

I have only 2 ways to load system with intel graphics:

- `nomodeset` in grub loader, which makes my screen 640x480, but still manages to boot
- `acpi=off` in grub loader, which **turns off** my **touchpad**, but works as well.

I am an user of ASUS FX503VD laptop with Intel Core i5-7300HQ and NVIDIA GTX 1050 (4gb).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try enabling intel graphics and set that to default in the bios.

Comment: @BernardWei I have ASUS motherboard, and BIOS is really bad on these motherboards, I actually can't do this.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change it with the 'nvidia-settings' tool instead of doing it from the cli?

Comment: @BernardWei Actually it makes no difference :( Still thanks for a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made it work on Ubuntu 18.04 lts by following this guide (https://askubuntu.com/a/923216/847770)

**WARNING**  Ubuntu 16.04 is not competible with this guide because of libssl 1.1 is not supported, which makes iASL work bad.

Now I can switch my cards with any freezes :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same laptop 
just update your kernel to >= 4.15.0-29-generic
and Nvidia drivers to Nvidia-390

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention, I have 4.17rc6 kernel. But i will try to install 390 drivers, and will answer you as soon as possible